# two and's in a pdo select

Tags: php, pdo, php-5.3

Ok so i am trying to recode my  staff panel from mysql to pdo and it seems like pdo does not allow 2 and statement in side the were.

This is what i have so far

Here is my basic html form

```
<form name="input" action="" method="post">
  <p>Username:</p>
  <p>
  <input type="text" name="username" id ="username">
  </p>
  <p>Password:  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="password" name="password" id = "password">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name = "Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

And then i do a if is set for the submit button

```
   if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$username2 = strip_tags($username);


$password= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$password2 = strip_tags($password);
$md5password = md5($password2);

$mod = 1 ;

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND mod = ?");
$statement->execute(array($username2,$md5password,$mod));
$count = $statement->rowCount();

/// If username and password is correct then we carry on
if ($count == "1")
  {


     $_SESSION['username'] = $username2 ; 

//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}



$result5534453465 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastip='".$ip."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());  

mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_log (username, ip)
VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$ip."')");






  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=home.php">';    
    exit;




  }else{
    echo "Password or username is wrong";  

  }
}
```

If i take the second AND out it works fine but of course i need it so only staff can login
I echo out the username and the md5 password both work fine and match the db entry. Has i have said if i remove the second And all works fine but i need the second And there so only staff can login. What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: You can only trust `$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`, other IP sources are unreliable

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string/strip_tags is not required and md5 is not safe for password hashing.

Comment: It is not pdo that is causing issues with adding a second `AND` to your query, as pdo->prepare can take complex queries easily. If it is failing then it is most likely due to an error in your query or your table / rows.

Comment: If i remove the second and and the mod bit it all works perfect...

Comment: what is the data type of `mod` in your table, and does they user you are selecting have a value of 1?

Comment: Yes its int and all mod's are set to 1 and users are set to 0

Comment: have you tried running the query directly in mysql to make sure it works / returns a row?

Comment: yes and it works. Also if i use SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?   in the pdo select all works but has soon has i add the AND mod but it stops working it goes to the else and says the password is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MOD` is a mysql reserved word - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html so it needs to be escaped -

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND `mod` = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in the PDO extension but looking at the manual it may be that you can only use the array in the $statement->execute() if the parameters are all strings (or at least all the same type)? Where they are mixed, as in your case, you may want to use the more complex versions of the execute method - separating out the bindParams functions. e.g.:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND mod = ?");
// $statement->execute(array($username2,$md5password,$mod));

$statement->bindParam(1, $username2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50); // check your lengths
$statement->bindParam(2, $md5password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 60);
$statement->bindParam(3, $mod, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

Does this work any better?

Comment: Haha!! I did wonder about mod but thought someone more experienced would have spotted it straight away. It's often the simplest things;)